# Add keyboard shortcut in Microsoft Word to open context menu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, context-menu, microsoft-word-2016

I've been using Visual Studio very frequently as of late, and I'm very used to pressing `ALT+ENTER` to bring up the Intellisense context menu. However, Intellisense is (unfortunately) not included with Microsoft Word, and I seemingly cannot stop pressing `ALT+ENTER` to bring up the menu when I misspell something - inserting a newline instead of being of any help. How can I bind `ALT+ENTER` to the context menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoHotkey can do this.  It's an app/scripting language to automate and remap key and mouse bindings.
https://www.autohotkey.com/

```
!Enter::MouseClick, Right
```

! is shorthand for Alt.  So this script is saying "When Alt + Enter is pressed, right click the mouse once."

I would imagine you could add logic to your script to only remap Alt+Enter while Word is active.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I completely forgot about AutoHotkey.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> open the context menu in Microsoft Word